# Como criar um navegador de pastas no java swing?

Tags: java, swing

Quero criar uma janela e nela tenha um botão, quando o usuário clicar nesse botão apareça aquele "navegador de pastas tipico do windows" para o usuário selecionar uma pasta da maquina dele e o endereço da pasta seja salvo em uma variável.
Isso é possível? Eu não sei como fazer para abrir esse "navegador de pastas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um componente chamado [**JFileChooser**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)  que possibilita seleção de arquivos do sistema de arquivos, através de uma janela que se abre, retornado o caminho desse arquivo, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]]

[**JTree**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) também pode ser usado para navegação, apesar da aparência ser um tanto quanto estranha e provavelmente não retornar nada como o componente anteriormente citado. Sua aparencia é essa:

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]]

Para a maioria das necessidades em aplicações que precisam acessar o sistema de arquivos corrente, os dois componentes costumam servir bem, para algo mais especifico e customizado, ai você precisa estudar a API e criar por contra propria ou personalizar o `JFileChooser`.